# NBA2k12 vs NBA2k13

Tags: nba2k12, nba2k13

I love the NBA2k series, but I'm wondering if the newest one is different enough for me to enjoy it. What are the major differences in the two versions?

I am mostly interested in My Player mode, but any differences that you know of are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2K13 did away with the whole money thing and went back to a skill points based system.  Instead of being paid money every pay period, you get more skill points, which you can spend on the usual stats.  However, you can also use skill points to increase the max stat cap (up to a limit I believe so you still can't have a center with 99 speed), and to purchase signature skills and animations.

They also added in something called signature skills, which are also purchased by skill points.  Signature skills are like 'equipment' your player can use, you are given 5 slots to equip signature skills, and they all have some effect.  For example, one of them boosts your teammate's overall defensive stats by 2 when equipped.  Another one guarantees that your teammate will pass you the ball when you call for it.

The gameplay is not much different though, and the commentators are still as bland and repetitive as ever.  Also, since the game was released before several major nba trades just before the season started, you'll need to download a roster update (but none of the commentators will be talking about those major trades).

Comment: im trying to play nba 2014 4 days and install it . and now have many questions? why no one here about 2k14?

Comment: @sabertabatabaeeyazdi not many nba fans I guess.  Feel free to post your questions though

Answer (score 0):

In NBA 2K13, players are a bit slower and you can't rush all game, because the stamina is more sensitive. The new control setting is also better for ball handling and crossovers.

I also think the social network messages are really cool.